# React: new Set(array) is not updated when re-rendered

Tags: reactjs

I'm confused about below behavior.
When I clicked "clicked me", `test` is updated correctly but `testSet` is not updated.
To be precise, testSet is updated only once and the length of `testSet` never be more than 5.

useTest.ts

```js
import { useState } from "react";

export const useTest = () => {
  const [test, setTest] = useState(["orange", "apple", "banana"]);
  const testSet = new Set(test);
  console.log(test)
  console.log(testSet)

  const increment = () => {
    test.push("grape");
    setTest([...test]);
    // setTest(newTest);
  };

  return { test, testSet, increment}

}
```

[image]

The entire code is below.

App.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { Test } from './Test';
// import { Test2 } from './Test2';

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Test />
      {/* <Test2 /> */}
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Test.tsx

```
import { useTest } from "./hooks/useTest";

export const Test = () => {
  const {test, testSet, increment} = useTest();

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Test1</h1>
      <h2>{test}</h2>
      <h2>{testSet}</h2>
      <button onClick={() => {increment()}}>Click me</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: It's not clear why you expect the set to contain the same value twice, can you explain?

Comment: `test.push("grape");` changing state directly is not a recommended practice. `setTest(pre => [...pre, 'grape']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `set` is a data structure in JavaScript that deals with collections of unique values.
`grape` is not added to the `set` because it is a duplicate value.

Comment: Thank you! I understand that...
The suggestion of recommended practice is also helpful!